# Sorting an array with respect to values of an other array one after the other

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, expression

Given the following arrays (arr,indices) ,I need to sort the array with respect to  **(i[0])th** index in **ascending order** if **i[1] equals 0** and **descending order** if **i[1] equals 1** ,where i refers to each element of the indices array.

**Constraints**

```
1<= len(indices) <=10

1<= len(arr) <=10^4
```

**Example**

```
arr=[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[6,4,3]]

indices=[[2,0],[0,1]]
```

**required output**

```
[[4,2,1],[3,2,1],[6,4,3],[1,2,3]]
```

**Explanation**

first arr gets sorted with respect to 2nd index as `(indices[0][0]=2)` in ascending order as `(indices[0][1]=0)`

```
[[3,2,1],[ 4,2,1],[1,2,3],[6,4,3]]
```

then it gets sorted with 0th index as `(indices[1][0]=0)` in descending order as `(indices[1][1]=1)`

```
[[4,2,1],[3,2,1],[6,4,3],[1,2,3]]
```

**Note**

arr,indices need to be taken as input , so it is not possible for me to write  `arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[2],-x[0]))`

**My Approach**

I have tried the following but it is not giving the correct output

`arr.sort(key=lambda x:next(x[i[0]] if i[1]==0 else -x[i[0]] for i in indices))`

**My output**

```
[[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[1,2,3],[6,4,3]]
```

**Expected output**

```
 [[4,2,1],[3,2,1],[6,4,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This one requires a very complex key. It looks to me like you have many different layers of sorting, here, and earlier elements of `indices` take precedence over later elements, when sort order would be affected.

I think what the sorting key needs to do is return a tuple/iterable, where the first element to sort by is whatever the first element of `indices` says to do, and the second element to sort by (in case of a tie in the first) is whatever the second element of `indices` says to do, and so on.

In which case you'd want something like this (a nested comprehension inside the key lambda, to generate that tuple (or, list, in this case)):

```
arr=[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[6,4,3]]
indices=[[2,0],[0,1]]

out = sorted(arr, key=lambda a: [
        (-1 if d else 1) * a[i]
        for (i, d) in indices
    ])
# [[4, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [6, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

For sorting numbers only, you can use a quick hack of "multiply by -1 to sort descending instead of ascending". Which I did here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the stability:

```
from operator import itemgetter

for i, r in reversed(indices):
    arr.sort(key=itemgetter(i), reverse=r)
```

This doesn't use the negation trick, so it also works for data other than numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
>>> a
[[6, 4, 3], [4, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> i
[[2, 0], [0, 1]]
>>> for j in enumerate(i):                    
...     a.sort(key=lambda x:x[j[1][0]],reverse=False if j[1][1]==0 else True)
...     print(a)                                                          
...
[[3, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3], [6, 4, 3]]
[[6, 4, 3], [4, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Is this what you want?

I think in your second example is small mistake. It should be

```
[[6, 4, 3], [4, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]]
```

rather than

```
[[4,2,1],[3,2,1],[6,4,3],[1,2,3]]
```

this is under

> then it gets sorted with 0th index as (indices[1][0]=0) in descending order as (indices[1][1]=1)